# How to change text colour on a child structure HTML5

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having troubles understanding how to access certain elements in my css file.

What I am trying to do is change the text colour of the elements in my navbar.. This seems like it should be very basic but I need some clarification on how the class structure works with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">News <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="news-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Local News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Special Announcements</a></li>                              
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Traffic</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The items I am trying to access are these:

```
<li><a href="#">Local News</a></li>
```

Could someone please explain to me how this works?

Thanks

Comment: What CSS have you written so far?

Comment: Nothing worth showing.. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
.navbar li a {
  color: black;
}
```

this is telling your code that all `li` inside a `.navbar` div should have the black text colour.

It also has to go inside a `.css` file or in between `<style></style>` tags on your html.

Give this a try:

```
<style>
.navbar li a {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I originally thought this would work but it didn't do anything

Comment: Maybe that's because there is a colour set to your `a` tag, probably by bootstrap. You can add the `a` selector after `li` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

With this code I select `ul` elements with `class="dropdown-menu"`, then I select `li` childs and then again, `a` childs.

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #000; /* change as you like */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Some clarifications

In CSS, selectors are patterns used to select the element(s) you want to style.

Most important selectors are:

- Class selectors
- ID Selectors
- Element Selectors

#### Class selectors

If you have `<a class="link">Link Text</a>` in your document and want to select it, you may use:

```
.link{ color: red; }
```

#### ID selectors

In the same way, if you have `<a id="link">Link Text</a>` you may select it:

```
#link{ color: red }
```

#### Element selectors

In the same way, if you have `<a>Link Text</a>` you may select it:

```
a{ color: red }
```

You have also the option to combine these methods:

```
.navbar li a{
  color: red;
}
```

In the above selector (`.navbar li a`) you have:

1. `.navbar` ----------- Which is a **Class selector**
2. {SPACE} ----------- Which says **In that**
3. `li` ------------------ Which is an **Element selector**
4. {SPACE} ----------- Which says **In that**
5. `a` -------------------- Which is an **Element selector**

## 2. Answering your question

In your case you may select the `.dropdown-menu li a` like this:

```
.dropdown-menu li a{ color: red }
```

If you want to style it in a specific manner, please leave a comment.

Comment: The problem with the original question might be that they are trying to style the <li> instead of the <a>. You may want to talk about specificity of the <a> overriding the <li>'s color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want apply css for all `dropdown-menu` class

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a{
    color: red;
}
```

Or if you want specific only one dropdown menu, use it's id.

```
#features-menu li a {
   color: red;
}
```